# Handling long type argument in Scala

Tags: scala, types, arguments

```
object LPrimeFactor {
  def main(arg:Array[String]):Unit = {
  start(13195)
  start(600851475143)

  }

  def start(until:Long){

    var all_prime_fac:Array[Int] = Array()
    var i = 2
```

(compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

integer number too large

Even though I changed the arg type to Long, it's still not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the argument as a `Long` (notice the `L` at the end of the number):

```
start(600851475143L)
               // ^
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a Long literal you must add `L` to the end of it.

```
start(600851475143L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remember literals values, if you has not any type direct suffix, the compiler try to get your  numeric type values, such as **600851475143** as type **Int**, which is **32-bit length, two complement representation**

```
MIN_VALUE = -2147483648(- 2 ^ 31)  
MAX_VALUE = 2147483647(2 ^ 31 - 1)
```

**So please add right suffix on the literal value, as 600851475143L**

Comment: See the Scala language specification[1]:
> Integer literals are usually of type int, or of type long when followed by a L or l
suffix. Values of type int are all integer numbers between −2^31 and 2^31 − 1, inclusive. Values of type long are all integer numbers between −2^63 and 2^63 −1, inclusive.
> A compile-time error occurs if an integer literal denotes a number outside these
ranges.
[1] https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ProgrammingInScala-2.4.pdf